# Creating a list with variables and summing them up

Tags: r

I created 15 variabeles called R_1 ... R_15. Each of the variabeles has a value.

I would like to to get the sum of all values. Of course I can do R_1+R_2 etc... But as I to perform this operation times I would like to automate this.

Have the feeling I have to create a list and then loop over  the list. Like:

```
list <- paste("R_", 1:15, sep="")
for (i in list) {
  var i = 0
  #sum up
  list[i] + 0
 }
```

But then I shouldnt get the variable but the amount calculated. Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Comment: your code has an error in the syntax at `var i = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the values of the character 'list' in a `list` and then use `Reduce` with `+` to sum all the elements of the `list` together.

```
Reduce(`+`, mget(list))
```

Or another option is `colSums` after `rbind`ing the `list` elements.

```
colSums(do.call(rbind, mget(list)))
```

If there is only a single element for each `R_number`,

```
sum(unlist(mget(list)))
```